# SQL Find earliest starting date

Tags: sql, oracle

I've been stuck on this for so long and I can't figure out/find the answer anywhere online.

So I have this code so far:

```
select c.country_olympic_name, 
       max(sg_start) 
  from summergames a, 
       country c
 where a.country_isocode = c.country_isocode
 group by c.country_isocode
HAVING max(sg_start) = (select max(sg_start) 
                          from summergames 
                         group by country_isocode)
 order by c.country_isocode;
```

What it needs to do is to find out the earliest starting date of the competitions..

I got it to work but then as soon as I added `country_olympic_name` which is in a different table to that of the `sg_start` it gives me this error:

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
>   00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"

Comment: Try adding the `country_olympic_name` in the `GROUP BY` statement.

Comment: If you want the *earliest* date, why does the query use `max()`?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the oldest/newest date use a simple aggregation, MIN(sg_date).

But if you want all columns for that date you have to switch to OLAP functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
 (
   SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER()
      OVER (-- when you want the earliest date per country: PARTITION BY c.country_isocode
            ORDER BY sg_start) AS rn -- use DESC for newest date
   FROM summergames a, country c
   WHERE a.country_isocode = c.country_isocode
 ) dt 
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY c.country_isocode;
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
select c.country_olympic_name, min(sg_start) 
from summergames a join
     country c
    on a.country_isocode = c.country_isocode
group by c.country_olympic_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Any field that is in the SELECT that is *not* an aggregation must be in the GROUP BY as well. Otherwise, the SQL engine doesn't know how to group by non-aggregated. You can change your SQL to the following:

```
select c.country_olympic_name, max(sg_start) 
  from summergames a, country c
 where a.country_isocode = c.country_isocode
 group by c.country_isocode, c.country_olympic_name
having max(sg_start) = ( select max(sg_start) 
                           from summergames 
                          group by country_isocode)
order by c.country_isocode;
```

Comment: Hi, if you highlight your code and click `{}` (or indent by 4 spaces) it will be marked up, which will make it more readable.